# Networking: NAT two interfaces together on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, networking, routing, openvpn

I have the following setup:

- Openvpn client (Linux) (Openvpn IP `192.168.99.4`)
- Openvpn client (Windows) (Openvpn IP `192.168.99.2`)
- Openvpn server (Linux) (Openvpn IP `192.168.99.1`)

Now, both clients connect to the server. From the Linux client, I want to be able to access the subnet of the ethernet interface (`10.137.137.0/24`) of the Windows client. This subnet has a number of other devices on it.

This is what I managed to get so far:

From the Linux client, I am able to ping the windows client on the other interface by adding another route:

```
sudo ip route add 10.137.137.0/24 via 192.168.99.2
```

Unfortunately, I am only able to ping the Windows client `10.137.137.1`, not other devices on that subnet (e.g., `10.137.137.2`).

I want to be able to do this.

Some further info: here is the client-specific openvpn configuration for my windows client:

```
iroute 10.137.137.0 255.255.255.0
```

Furthermore, I have enabled IP forwarding on the Windows machine in `regedit`.

I know that this post is very similar to [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/877085/windows-10-as-a-router-nat-incoming-nic-1-traffic-out-via-nic-2), but I cannot configure Routing and Remote Access on my machine (as shown in the answer), as the option is simply not there in the admin tools.

Moreover, I know I can manually add a route on `10.137.137.2` to route requests from the OpenVPN interface to `10.137.137.1`, but this does not scale well in a large network.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by enabling Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) on the ethernet interface, sharing it with the OpenVPN interface. Finally, I restored the IP address of the OpenVPN interface, as Windows changed it in the process of enabling ICS.